# Creating a Macro to sort items by date entered (results triggered from formula)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, macros

I have Sheet 1 where I am entering in new data on a worksheet, and on my Reference sheet I am pulling the same values from sheet 1 in so that I can sort them by time entered.  My goal is to have a display on Sheet 1 that shows the last 10 items entered on Sheet 1. I used the formula below to sort my Reference sheet by date, but since I am using a formula to pull in the values it does not trigger.  Is it possible to combine this with a new macro so that I can enter data in one place and have it sorted elsewhere?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A As Range
    Dim AB As Range
    Set A = Range("A:A")
    Set AB = Range("A:B")

    If Intersect(Target, A) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.Offset(0, 1) = Now
        AB.Sort Key1:=Range("B1"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo, _
            OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
            DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your issue is that your macro code is not triggered for the change in one sheet because the sheet is changing just by virtue of a formula reference. If this is the case, can you not put the code (or a call whatever Subs you need) from the **Workbook_SheetChange()** Sub instead? (the 'Workbook's **SheetChange()** event will trigger when you change *any* sheet). You can inspect the sheet that was changed using **Sh.Name** from within this Sub. And get the cell address of the change using **Target.Address**.